# копирование данных из буфера в openGL 4

Tags: opengl

у меня есть 2 буфера типа `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` мне нужно скопировать все данные из буфера 1 в буфер 2.

я попытался использовать `glCopyBufferSubData` но копирования не происходит.

пример

```
    int[] id = new int[2];
    float[] data= new float[]{
            1,2,3
    };
    float[] data2 = new float[]{
            4,5,6
    };
    gl.glGenBuffers(2,id,0);
    int buf1 = id[0];
    int buf2 = id[1];

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,buf1);
    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,data.length*4,FloatBuffer.wrap(data),GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    FloatBuffer ret = GLBuffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(data.length);
    gl.glGetBufferSubData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,data.length*4,ret);
    System.out.println("буфер 1");
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.capacity(); i++){
        System.out.print(ret.get() + " ");
    }
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,buf2);
    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,data2.length*4,FloatBuffer.wrap(data2),GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    ret = GLBuffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(data2.length);
    gl.glGetBufferSubData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,data2.length*4,ret);
    System.out.println("\nбуффер 2");
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.capacity(); i++){
        System.out.print(ret.get() + " ");
    }
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

    gl.glCopyBufferSubData(buf2,buf1,0,0,data2.length*4);
    System.out.println();
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,buf1);
    ret = GLBuffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(data.length);
    gl.glGetBufferSubData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,data.length*4,ret);
    System.out.println("буфер 1");
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.capacity(); i++){
        System.out.print(ret.get() + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Приведите фрагменты кода по созданию и копированию буферов

Comment: Также проверьте/приведите код ошибки `glGetError` если он есть

Comment: И как вы понимаете что ничего не скопировалось?

Answer (score 1):

Мы не можем привязать два буфера одновременно к одному и тому же предназначению буфера. Именно поэтому OpenGL предоставляет нам еще два дополнительных предназначения для буферов: GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER и GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER. Далее мы связываем выбранные буферы с новыми предназначениями и указываем предназначения в качестве readtarget и writetarget аргументов.
Источник: https://ravesli.com/urok-25-rasshirennye-metody-vzaimodejstviya-s-dannymi-v-opengl/
Внизу страницы можно увидеть раздел "Копирование буфферов".
Сам пробовал второй вариант из статьи. Выглядит так:

glCopyNamedBufferSubData(source->VBO, destination->VBO, 0, 0, 16 * sizeof(GLfloat));
glCopyNamedBufferSubData(source->EBO, destination->EBO, 0, 0,  6 * sizeof(GLuint));

Только перед копированием нужно обязательно иметь имя буффера (Создать при помощи **glGenBuffer()**), привязать это имя к целевому буфферу через **glBindbuffer()**, и обязательно!!! выделить память для хранения. Последнее я делал через **glBufferData()** и передавал **NULL** вместо данных.

Мой полигон, копируется в объект с другими vbo и ebo, затем текстура и т.д. И всё рисуется как надо.